# How to map an object to a specific item ID using Glass Mapper attributes?

Tags: glass-mapper

I have a class where I have a set of objects such as:

```
[SitecoreQuery("./*[@@templateid='" + MyItem.TemplateId + "']", IsRelative = true, IsLazy = false)]
public virtual IEnumerable<MyItem> MyItems { get; set; }
```

Now I would like to add a new object which would be mapped to a specific item ID, rather than a template. I've therefore tried adding:

```
[SitecoreQuery("//*[@@id='{" + MySpecificItem.RootId + "}']", IsRelative = false, IsLazy = false)]
public virtual MySpecificItem MyItem { get; set; }
```

However Glass Mapper seems to return a null object when I run the code. I could map the object using *Sitecore.Context.Database.GetItem* within the constructor, however I'd prefer to use the attributes for consistency.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you try this?

```
[SitecoreNode(Id = MySpecificItem.RootId)]
public virtual MySpecificItem MyItem { get; set; }
```

It sounds good regarding to the [source code](https://github.com/mikeedwards83/Glass.Mapper/blob/8f4506a14b7c1cd3f9179ed6459741c73fa7ea1a/Source/Glass.Mapper.Sc/Configuration/Attributes/SitecoreNodeAttribute.cs) of Glass.Mapper.

Comment: It works, thank you. Its a shame Glass Mapper doesn't have proper documentation.

Comment: @JonathanReez it's amazingly bad and possibly intentional